# GNU Make: create wildcard based on a word list

Tags: makefile

I have several library source code files organized as follows in a separate directory (out of my project src):

```
/path/to/libsrc/file_clock.c
/path/to/libsrc/file_spi.c
/path/to/libsrc/file_dma.c
/path/to/libsrc/file_i2c.c
```

etc. and I don't need all of them. For example, I could need only `file_clock.c` and `file_spi.c`.

Is it possible to use a list to use only the source code file I need ?
For example, what I would like to is something like:

```
MODULES = spi clock
C_SRC += $(wildcard /path/to/libsrc/*$(MODULES)*.c)
```

but this doesnt work since `MODULE` is a space separated word list.
How can I achieve this if possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running $(wildcard ...) multiple times is an awful idea. Instead, it could be something like this:

```
MODULES := spi clock
C_SRC += $(filter $(patsubst %,\%/file_%.c,$(MODULES)),$(wildcard /path/to/libsrc/*.c))
```

Comment: The `filter` solution is the best because it match exactely the MODULES keyword. For example, without it, if I have `file_spi.c` and `file_qspi.c`, this one last will be compiled too if I don't need it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

```
MODULES = spi clock
C_SRC += $(foreach var, $(MODULES), $(wildcard /path/to/libsrc/*$(var)*.c))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MODULES = spi clock
C_SRC += $(foreach var, $(MODULES), $(wildcard /path/to/libsrc/*$(var)*.c))
```

This would be the most recommended approach instead of filtering

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
C_SRC += $(wildcard $(patsubst %,/path/to/libsrc/file_%.c,$(MODULES)))
```